# Python selenium h

Tags: python, selenium

I get an **"selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="username"]"** when trying to login to the site, what can I do?

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get("https://tr.pilot.darkorbit.com/community/")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("aaase")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("bbbb")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("bgcdw_button bgcdw_login_form_login").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()
```

site:

```
<form name="bgcdw_login_form" method="post" class="bgcdw_login_form" action="https://sas.bpsecure.com/Sas/Authentication/Bigpoint?authUser=22&amp;token=AhDfvh-wPispzDuutUzjZkBZ53XaPjktIJ_B_UDBjraljR__1oMOr9LNpV7hifoElG21nzuHgeS9h8SFFvLsnfgGTcGvG53RMyISXJbj_td5t-j_g94BImmZp5P-ZOCrFNkuBU1Ifxdlv3H2TutvEC0png4CufHp0h69swHlwxJmqFCL6YqN11-fjiAHO0HwkoaQ2y9iEo4ZTzGvDSiEzaU-c2NTpIuSL8WyjJUVaNGPUNQ41wvt2Nz9Z8jXa6Zy45A4B9E6bAuY5XxF6t29-dRni9vHfyxeTgUlD9NkFRc7MNUz70nBtxHJoARdE08KVsJ9W8hPDjfRvQ3Zuaa3loOi2iY-WJ5w2iXtNIJ-8lx4MFqhQNLE8ZgXO22f9HBAvMQw2zac2C4IXTb1yy0WlLo41lUUefTsBV4Epjfn8K4" novalidate="novalidate" target="_parent">
        <div class="bgc_error_translations" style="display:none">
            <div data-error-key="bgc.error.username_isTooShort">Seçtiğin üye ismi çok kısa. Lütfen yeni bir üye ismi gir ve adın en az 4 en uzun 20 karakterden oluşmasına dikkat et.</div>
            <div data-error-key="bgc.error.username_isTooLong">Seçtiğin üye ismi çok uzun. Lütfen yeni bir üye ismi gir ve adın en az 4 en uzun 20 karakterden oluşmasına dikkat et.</div>
            <div data-error-key="bgc.error.username_notGiven">Üye adını gir</div>
            <div data-error-key="bgc.error.password_isTooShort">Seçtiğin şifre çok kısa. Lütfen yeni şifre gir ve şifrenin en az 4 ve en uzun 45 karakterden oluşmasına dikkat et.</div>
            <div data-error-key="bgc.error.password_isTooLong">Seçtiğin şifre çok uzun. Lütfen yeni şifre gir ve şifrenin en az 4 ve en uzun 45 karakterden oluşmasına dikkat et.</div>
            <div data-error-key="bgc.error.password_notGiven">Lütfen şifreni gir.</div>
            <div data-error-key="bgc.error.email_invalidAddress">E-mail adresin doğru değil. Lütfen geçerli bir e-posta adresi gir.</div>
            <div data-error-key="bgc.error.email_notGiven">E-posta adresini yazar mısın?</div>
            <div data-error-key="bgc.error.checkbox_tick">Lütfen kutuyu işaretleyin.</div>
        </div>
        <fieldset class="bgcdw_login_form_login"><div class="bgcdw_input_text bgcdw_login_form_username">
                <label for="bgcdw_login_form_username" style="display: none;">Kullanıcı adı</label>
                <input id="bgcdw_login_form_username" name="username" type="text" maxlength="20" placeholder="Kullanıcı adı"></div>
            <div class="bgcdw_input_password bgcdw_login_form_password">
                <label for="bgcdw_login_form_password" style="display: none;">Şifre</label>
                <input id="bgcdw_login_form_password" name="password" type="password" maxlength="45" placeholder="Şifre"></div>
        </fieldset><div class="bgcdw_login_container_remindpassword">
            <a class="bgcdw_remindpassword" target="_parent" href="https://accountcenter.bpsecure.com/PasswordReminder?pid=22&amp;lang=tr_TR" data-analyticslabel="web-login-link-remindpassword">Şifremi unuttum!</a>
        </div>
        <fieldset class="bgcdw_login_form_buttons"><button class="bgcdw_button bgcdw_login_form_login" type="submit">Giriş</button><button class="bgcdw_button bgcdw_login_form_register" type="button" onclick="window.location='/frame';return false;">Kaydol</button></fieldset></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If input doesnt show in frame, you must scroll browser to related area for show elements.. Selenium works with remote control, so it is not parse content before load.

When page load, you see everthing fine, but element cannot located, because some elements may place bottom of page and this unvisible elements cannot parse for browsers, in truth they are in the RAM (memory).

Also, sleep not recommended for detect page loading, you should search in  google and SO with these keywords; selenium wait for page load.

Comment: burak türkçe söyler misin

Comment: sayfanın yüklenmesi için "driver.set_page_load_timeout(3)" yazdım ama yine de olmadı

Comment: set_load_timeout aradığınız şey değil. Sayfanın yüklendiğinden emin olduktan sonra, input'un da görünür olduğundan emin olmalısınız.

Comment: kod şu şekilde çalışmaya başladı :                                                 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.set_page_load_timeout(4)

driver.get("https://lp.darkorbit.com/")


time.sleep(3)

Comment: maximize_window ile input'u görünür kılmışsınız muhtemelen, fakat her site için farklı yerlerde olabilir aradığınız şeyler, dolayısıyla iyi bir algoritma geliştirip browserın sayfayı scroll yapmasını sağlamanız sağlıklı olacaktır.

Comment: Burak bey, benim algoritmam deneme yanılma yolu, bilginiz için teşekkür ederim, takıldığım bir nokta olursa buraya yazarım, kolay gelsin

Comment: Cevabı kabul ettiğiniz için bende teşekkür ederim, elimden geldiğince yardımcı olurum, ama ingilizce olursa daha iyi olur burası global biryer herkes faydalansın..

Comment: ingilizce bilmiyorum,google translateden çevirip paylaşırım o zaman